# Cannot setup two-factor authentication

Tags: icloud, security

I'm trying to set up 2FA on my iCloud account but I get this message:

[image]

Any ideas on a solution? There's also no option in the security settings on my iPhone to enable it. I'm running the latest versions of iOS and macOS.

Comment: Where you running a beta OS on either devices prior to updating to the latest versions?  I've seen people have problems if they where running a beta.  Also, try changing your Apple ID security questions and make sure you have a credit card on your account (Apple uses that to verify identity).

Comment: Is the option available to you at id.apple.com? Do you have any old devices listed there?

Answer (score 2):

Thought I'd share because I went down the rabbit hole on this and it turned out pretty simple.

I was not able to turn on two factor authenication because I had a couple of old apple devices (an old iphone 4 i was using for music and a phone that hadn't been charged in 5 years) that DID NOT HAVE A PASSCODE ENABLED.

Apple wasn't able to turn on two factor unless every device on my appleid account had a password set.

I just deleted from my account and it worked.  This took a week of back and forth with (a very nice) apple rep.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue.

In my case I apparently missed/junked/deleted the verification email sent to me by Apple.  A call into support and they resent the email and I was good to go.

Before you call a quick search of your email for appleid@id.apple.com might save you some time.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

If you have enabled two-step-verification you need to disable it first. 
Go to your AppleID website, login and edit the security section. Disable the two-step-verification.

If you're ready with that, you can try to enable the two-factor-authentication on your device.

AppleID Website: https://appleid.apple.com/#!&page=signin

Comment: The OP states he's running the latest OS versions on both Mac and iPhone so how does this answer the question?

Comment: misreading the OP's questions :( . I've correct my answer.